# bootstrap table: I'm unable to achieve give background to first of the rows with same priority?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-table

I have a bootstrap table. Which looks like [image]

as you can see i have one red background high priority. I want the first medium to be yellow and first low to be some other color. 
I'm trying to do this with data-cell-style. Is there other better ways which I can do here?

What I've tried so far.

```
var i = 0;
  function colorPriority(value, row, index){
    var classes = ['danger', 'warning', 'secondary'];
    if(value == "high"){  
      if(i == 0){
        i++;  
        return {
          classes: classes[0]
        }
      }    
    }
    if(value == "medium"){ 
    i--; 
      if(i == 0){
        i++;
        return {
          classes: classes[1]
        }
      }    
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If it were me I'd probably just forego the additional JS and instead just let css do it for ya with an attribute selector by appending one with the cell string value as the attribute and be done like;

HTML: `<td data-priority="High">High</td>`

CSS: `[data-priority="High"]:first-of-type {background:red}`

Since you know the string will be a fixed "High", "Medium", "Low" in this instance...

Comment: that sounds great!!.. but i just want to know if I'm able to achieve with bootstrap cell-style. I may encounter something like this on future.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is for table with id=table_one with field=directing_field and values 1,2,3 respectively being danger, warning, info colored I would add into js

```
var danger_cell = 0;
var warning_cell = 0;
var info_cell = 0;
if ($("#table_one").length > 0){
     $("#table_one").bootstrapTable({
          cellStyle: function cellStyle(value,index,field) {
               if (field==='directing_field') {
                    if (value===1) {
                         if ((danger_cell===0) || (index < danger_cell)) {
                              danger_cell = index;
                              return { classes:'bg-danger' }
                         } else {return} 
                    } else if (value===2) {
                         if ((warning_cell===0) || (index < warning_cell)) {
                              warning_cell = index;
                              return { classes:'bg-warning' }
                         } else {return}
                    } else if (value===3) {
                         if ((info_cell===0) || (index < info_cell)) {
                              info_cell = index;
                              return { classes:'bg-info' }
                         } else {return}
                    } else {return}
               } 
          },
          onSort: function () {
               danger_cell = 0;
               warning_cell = 0;
               info_cell = 0;
          },
          onRefresh: function () {
               danger_cell = 0;
               warning_cell = 0;
               info_cell = 0;
          }
     });
}
```

of course that is if your table is pure HTML if it is JS produced then just add the options into yours...